# How do I change the type of an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

By default, C# enums are stored as integers. I'd like to make it a short instead. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sure, this can be done, but it has to be an integral type ( byte, short, int, etc.) except char...

```
enum myEnum : short
{
    FirstValue = 0,
};
```

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.71).aspx) is the MSDN docs

Comment: I blame my office's internet connection. =)

Comment: @rockinthesixstring what else would you expect from the Kwisatz Haderach? ;)

Comment: @Maud'Dib - i think char is the exception. i dont think it is allowed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Heh thanks, much easier than I thought it'd be! I actually read the doc but didn't scroll down far enough to see the part where uses the inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
enum MyEnum : short
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it makes more sense to have String values as enums you can use Attributes and achieve this check this link http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create enum like

```
enum Range : short {Max = 6, Min = 1, Mid = 3};
```